# getting error on migrating raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to " TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using djongo to connect my rest_framework API with MongoDB. I have deleted the 0001_initial.py file and try to push the migrations using `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` but I am getting these errors while doing this.

**my settings.py file**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'TMS',
    }
}
```

```
(env) D:\inductionplan\django-api\backend>python manage.py migrate        
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, api, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions, token_blacklist
Running migrations:
This version of djongo does not support "NULL, NOT NULL column validation check" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using CONSTRAINT" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using KEY" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using REFERENCES" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...This version of djongo does not support "COLUMN DROP NOT NULL " fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "DROP CASCADE" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 894, in _alter
    query.execute()
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 533, in _drop_column    
    self.db[self.left_table].update(
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2584, in __call__
    raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to "
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'update' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 784, in __init__        
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 885, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: ALTER TABLE "django_content_type" DROP COLUMN "name" CASCADE
        Params: ()
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute       
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 417, in execute    
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 90, in wrapped     
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 253, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 126, in migrate  
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 156, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 236, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 125, in apply   
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 162, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 569, in remove_field
    self.execute(sql)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 151, in execute 
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute        
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute        
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute       
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute       
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\backend\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\backend\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 386, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 213, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 305, in close     
    self._close()
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\base.py", line 208, in _close
    if self.connection:
  File "D:\inductionplan\django-api\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 829, in __bool__
    raise NotImplementedError("Database objects do not implement truth "
NotImplementedError: Database objects do not implement truth value testing or bool(). Please compare with None instead: database is not None
```

Comment: you use `djongo` and use database **MongoDB**,but  the currect database would be **MangoDB**. But I am not sure if django support **MangoDB** or not.